# Controller to Observer Conversion?

Tags: event-observer, controllers, magento-2.1.10

I am new to Magento 2 modules and would like to create a module to run the below class whenever someone accesses the homepage. I believe it would be easier if I converted this to an observer so I just wanted to confirm that that was as simple as reconfiguring the below code block.

```
<?php
namespace Webkul\Module\Controller\DemoController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class DemoClass extends Action {
    private $remoteAddress;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
    ) {
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is working for you??

Answer (score 0):

> You can use event controller_action_postdispatch_cms_index_index for
> home page
>
> 1. Create "events.xml" file inside your extension folder
>    Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_cms_index_index">
        <observer name="mymodule_controller_home_action" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Home"  />
    </event> 
</config>
```

> 2. Create Observer file "Home.php" under Vendor/Module/Observer/Home.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class Home implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $remoteAddress;    

    public function __construct(RemoteAddress $remoteAddress)
    {
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {        
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
        return $this;
    }
}
```